# String greater-than-less-than Tests Against a Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for matches between an alphabetically sorted list of strings and a regular expression using python.

The regular expression is relatively simple, something like "block_number_[0-9]+", representing "block_number_" followed by any string that represents a number, e.g. "block_number_1234".

Beyond the alphabetical sorting, there is very little structure to the strings in the list; it also contains entries like "block_number_alt567" and "block_no_90210".

Is there a way to test for when I have passed the point in my list of strings where a match to my regular expression is no longer possible, i.e. once I hit block_number_alt567, there's no need to test for any more matches to "block_number_[0-9]+" ?

(The ultimate goal is to compare a relatively long list of strings, to a list of regular expressions which captures all of the variations in the list; the performance savings from not searching every element of the string list every time will be significant in the application environment).

Answer (score 2):

The nice part about regex is that you can use one regex to match many patterns. The following regex matches all of your example patterns.

```
block_n(o|(um(ber)?))_\w*\d+
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I never would have come up with that on my own.  However, I also have the situation where different string variations require different processing right after a match is determined, so I do need to search against a list of regular expressions.

Comment: If you need different processing, then yes, you would have to match your string against a list of regexes to control your flow. Is your file only made up of `number_block...` strings, or do those need to be extracted from surrounding text?

Comment: They don't need to be extracted, each string is already a single line in an ASCII file.  The regular expressions are also input through a text-file; the design goal is to write a python script that I can distribute to to others, where they can input their own regular expressions, and the script will compare the user input to the list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Python strings alphabetically with < and >. For instance, `"block_number_0" < "block_number_alt567"` is True.

If I understand you correctly, then you can stop looking if the regular expression doesn't match and the string is greater than "block_number_0" (or any other number).

Comment: Does this mean I have to manually determine & add a "minimum" matching pattern for every regular expression in my list, or can determining minimum matches be somehow done automatically?

Comment: I thought it was only this single regular expression, sorry. I can't think of a really generic, easy way to find an example of a matching pattern right now. Do all the regular expressions start with a fixed part (like "block_number_")? In that case you could sort the regular expressions themselves, the place where one stops matching is the place where the next would start matching.

Comment: No problem; I kept the scope of my Q narrow, to make sure I was expressing myself clearly.  The list of strings I have is a godawful mess, with things that should be grouped together often having dissimilar syntax.  Think "50acre_number_of_cows" and "bovine_count_hundred_acres" as two possibilities.  The job of the python script is to compare the string list to a manually composed regex list of possible variations, and pull out everything in a related family.  Ultimately, other users besides me are supposed to be able to make up their own regex lists, and have everything work swimmingly!

Comment: Upon further review, this may work for my application.  If I treat the current regex pattern as a basic string, I can create its "minimum" boundary value using python's string.replace method to replace each instance of "[0-9]+" with "0".  It's not a perfectly generalizable solution, but should handle the level of text-complexity I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is sorted and you're trying to parse sets of entries, you can also read the data in (given your storage space is sufficient), and then do a binary search to find your blocks more effectively without processing every line individually.

For example if you have a list like the following:

```
block_no_0001
block_no_0023
< n random sorted block_no_ entries>
block_no_9451
block_number_0451
block_number_1582
< m random sorted block_number_... entries>
block_number_9825
block_number_alt1234
```

Then you read all the entries from the file into a list:

```
list = []
file = open('mytestfile.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines()
    list.append(line)
listlen = len(list)
```

You can then search through the list using a binary search to find the upper and lower bounds of all of your entries without having to try to match every line.  Then just process the sets of blocks differently without having to match all the entries between the indexes separately.

So for example you'd eventually store something in maybe a dictionary that looked like this:

```
{'block_number[0-9]{0,3}': 
     {'high': 450, 'low': 119}, 
 'block_no[\\w+][0-9]{0,3}': 
     {'high': 452, 'low': 451}, 
 'block_no[0-9]{0,3}': 
     {'high': 118, 'low': 0}
 }
```

You can then just blow through each of the dictionary entries from 'low' to 'high' and process as needed.